# notifyDataSetChanged not refreshing listview

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

Initially I get list of data from server and set it to listview.

When scrolling down the listview, I am getting collection of data from server and calling notifydatasetchanged of my custom adapter.

At getView() method of custom adapter, I am downloading an image from server by asyntask. When it is downloaded successfully and storing it locally. Then just trying to refresh list view at onPostExecute of that asyntask. But its not getting refresh.

The log at onPostExecute is printing but listview is not getting refresh.

public void loadBitmap(MainActivity mainActivity, String imageKey,ImageView imageView, boolean isScrolling) 
{
        final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(imageKey);

```
    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        if (!isScrolling && !mCurrentTasks.contains(imageKey)
                && mainActivity.internetIsAvailable()) {
            BitmapLoaderTask task = new BitmapLoaderTask(imageKey,
                    mainActivity.getAdapter());
            task.execute();
        }
    }
}

private class BitmapLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ListAdapter mListAdapter;
    private String mImageKey;

    public BitmapLoaderTask(String imageKey, ListAdapter adapter) {
        mListAdapter = adapter;
        mImageKey = imageKey;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mCurrentTasks.add(mImageKey);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mImageKey);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());

            if (b != null) {
                int width = b.getWidth();
                int height = b.getHeight();

                if (width >= mMaxWidth || height >= mMaxHeight) {
                    while (true) {
                        if (width <= mMaxWidth || height <= mMaxHeight) {
                            break;
                        }
                        width /= 2;
                        height /= 2;
                    }
                    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
                }

                connection.disconnect();
                addBitmapToCache(mImageKey, b);
                return b;
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap param) {
        mCurrentTasks.remove(mImageKey);
        if (param != null) {
            mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are downloading images and displaying i suggest you use UIL. Any way post the code if you don't like using third party libraries

Comment: Try to update your UI, in the onProgressUpdate() method from your asynctask.

Comment: I'm calling loadBitmap() method from above code at getview() of my custom adapter. ImageKey is URL and it will be stored in cache after downloaded. Initially i check in cache, if its is presented its getting load. Otherwise it will start to download and will be stored in cache at doInBackground().

Comment: I'm using listview and gridview in this activity and both are using the same custom adapter. Is that causes this issue..?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks right.. but i think what may be the issue is `mainActivity.getAdapter()` i think you should declare adapter globally like.

private AdapterYourCustomAdapter adapter;

and then in onCreate()

```
adapter = new AdapterYourCustomAdapter(context,arraylist(whatever constructor is));
```

and then pass that call it like:

```
if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        if (!isScrolling && !mCurrentTasks.contains(imageKey)
                && mainActivity.internetIsAvailable()) {
            new BitmapLoaderTask( imageKey, adapter ).execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to change data source for adapter to make it notify.. i mean here if (param != null) {
            mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } you are not adding or removing anythink from your adapter???

Comment: then why did u call mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?? if you are adding some data to ur listView or removing some data then only you will see effect of mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() this stattement.

Comment: You can see that above code. I'm getting image from local cache at initially. If image is not presented in cache, starting async task and dowloading image. After downloading finished, it will be saved in cache. To load that cached image to listview, i'm calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `ImageView` for each bitmap into the `BitmapLoaderTask` at construction and hold onto that `ImageView` as a member variable inside.  When you finish loading your bitmap, use the `onPostExecute` method to assign that bitmap as the `ImageView` drawable.

```java
private class BitmapLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

  private String mImageKey;
  private ImageView mImageView;

  public BitmapLoaderTask(ImageView imageView, String imageKey) {
    mImageView = imageView;
    mImageKey = imageKey;
  }

  protected void onPreExecute() {

    /* Pre execute stuff */

  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

    /* Your bitmap processing */

    return bitmap;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap param) {
    if(param != null) {
      mImageView.setImageBitmap(param);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a perfect example of what `AsyncTask` was built to do.  The `doInBackground()` method is run on a background thread and thus does not interfere with UI processing, but android permissions dictate that such background threads are not allowed to touch UI elements.  That's what the `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` are for, they run quick UI updates on the main UI thread whenever `doInBackground` has reached an update-worthy milestone.  In this case, you're using them to notify your ImageView objects when their corresponding bitmaps are ready.